# Transpose and Reorder

Tags: r, transpose

I have a dataframe of fantasy teams, and I would like to view it differently.

```
Position             Name Salary           GameInfo   FPPG teamAbbrev TeamSalary TotalPoints
9              RB  Devonta Freeman   8000  TB@Atl 01:00PM ET 28.443        Atl      49800     203.716
39             WR   Alshon Jeffery   6400 Min@Chi 01:00PM ET 22.250        Chi      49800     203.716
45             WR  Steve Smith Sr.   6100  SD@Bal 01:00PM ET 21.133        Bal      49800     203.716
47             QB      Andy Dalton   6000 Cin@Pit 01:00PM ET 24.957        Cin      49800     203.716
55             RB      Doug Martin   5500  TB@Atl 01:00PM ET 18.833         TB      49800     203.716
64             WR  Martavis Bryant   5300 Cin@Pit 01:00PM ET 25.150        Pit      49800     203.716
126            TE    Antonio Gates   4800  SD@Bal 01:00PM ET 24.350         SD      49800     203.716
128            WR     Stefon Diggs   4800 Min@Chi 01:00PM ET 21.433        Min      49800     203.716
383           DST         Broncos    2900  GB@Den 08:30PM ET 17.167        Den      49800     203.716
DST.391       DST          Giants    2700  NYG@NO 01:00PM ET  9.714        NYG      49800     190.930
QB.4           QB        Tom Brady   8300  Mia@NE 08:25PM ET 28.343         NE      49800     190.930
RB.137         RB   Danny Woodhead   4500  SD@Bal 01:00PM ET 17.214         SD      49800     190.930
RB.55          RB      Doug Martin   5500  TB@Atl 01:00PM ET 18.833         TB      49800     190.930
RB.9           RB  Devonta Freeman   8000  TB@Atl 01:00PM ET 28.443        Atl      49800     190.930
TE.126         TE    Antonio Gates   4800  SD@Bal 01:00PM ET 24.350         SD      49800     190.930
WR.64          WR  Martavis Bryant   5300 Cin@Pit 01:00PM ET 25.150        Pit      49800     190.930
WR.39          WR   Alshon Jeffery   6400 Min@Chi 01:00PM ET 22.250        Chi      49800     190.930
WR.145         WR Rishard Matthews   4300  Mia@NE 08:25PM ET 16.633        Mia      49800     190.930
```

I am trying transpose and manipulate it to get it to print,

```
team1 1  Devonta Freeman     Alshon Jeffery   Steve Smith Sr.        Andy Dalton       Doug Martin Martavis Bryant     Antonio Gates       Stefon Diggs          Broncos  49800   203.716

team2 2 Giants Tom Brady    Danny Woodhead       Doug Martin   Devonta Freeman     Antonio Gates Martavis Bryant     Alshon Jeffery  Rishard Matthews  49800 190.930
```

all of this in one row.  And remove the rest of the information.  Column names will be the same, but I can add those later.  Would be nice to order by position but not a big deal if I can't

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Well I see where you're going with this, but first off I'm not entirely R will let you have duplicated column names. You may need to have names such as RB1, RB2, WR1,WR2 etc.

Comment: You will also need to change your script in the order function. try: test1 <- order(test1$Position, c("QB", "RB", "RB", "WR", "WR", "WR", "TE", c("RB" | "WR" | "TE"), "DST")). You can't use the word "or" in the function

Comment: Thanks for the advise,  I have no problem changing the names.  Just tried your suggested order function and I got the following error.  Error in "RB" | "WR" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types.

Comment: hmm OK you may need to rename your columns first so try this. names(test1) = c("QB", "RB", "RB", "WR", "WR", "WR", "TE", "FLEX", "DST").

Comment: That still gave the same error

Comment: The tricky part is trying to get your WR/RB/TE to fill the FLEX position. Honestly the easiest thing to do might be to make a loop and fill each position by the max player projections

Comment: I think I will be fine without having any order.  Order would be nice, but might not be necessary.  If you can just help me get a row of player names and salary and points would be perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also works

```
test8 = teams
 test8$Name = as.character(test8$Name)

 test2=NULL
 for(j in 1:(nrow(test8)/9)){
     test = test8[1:9,]
 test3 = split(test, test$Position)
 if(nrow(test3$RB) == 3){
   test4 = as.data.frame(cbind(test3$QB$Name, test3$RB$Name[1], test3$RB$Name[2], test3$WR$Name[1], test3$WR$Name[2],test3$WR$Name[3],test3$TE$Name, test3$RB$Name[3], test3$DST$Name[1], test$TeamSalary[1], test$TotalPoints[1]))
   } else if(nrow(test3$WR) == 4){
   test4 = as.data.frame(cbind(test3$QB$Name, test3$RB$Name[1], test3$RB$Name[2], test3$WR$Name[1], test3$WR$Name[2],test3$WR$Name[3],test3$TE$Name, test3$WR$Name[4], test3$DST$Name[1], test$TeamSalary[1], test$TotalPoints[1]))
  } else {
   test4 = as.data.frame(cbind(test3$QB$Name, test3$RB$Name[1], test3$RB$Name[2], test3$WR$Name[1], test3$WR$Name[2],test3$WR$Name[3],test3$TE$Name, test3$TE$Name[2], test3$DST$Name[1], test$TeamSalary[1], test$TotalPoints[1]))
  }
     test2 = rbind(test2,test4)
     test8 = test8[-c(1:9),]
  }

colnames(test2) = c("QB", "RB", "RB", "WR", "WR", "WR", "TE", "FLEX", "DST", "TeamSalary", "TeamPoints")
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've updated the code to include an index column in my sample data frame. In my case its called "Index". In order to loop by the index I created a vector that extracted the unique levels (ind = unique(data$Index)), in this case only 1 and 2, but in your case 10,000 levels. Then in the "j" loop it will extract the data by each index and extract the required info for each of your teams.

```
data = as.data.frame(list(Position = c("WR","WR","QB","RB","WR","RB","WR","TE","DST"),
                      Name=c("Julio Jones","DeAndre Hopkins","Tom Brady","Devonta Freeman",
                             "Alshon Jeffery","Chris Ivory","Martavis Bryant",
                             "Antonio Gates","Broncos"),
                      Salary = c(9200,8700,8300,8000,6400,6000,5300,4800,2900),
                      FPPG = c(25.143,25.657,28.343,28.443,22.250,20.300,
                               25.150,24.350,17.167),
                      TeamSalary = rep(59600,9),
                      TotalPoints = rep(216.803,9),
                      Index = rep(1,9)))

data1 = as.data.frame(list(Position = c("WR","WR","QB","RB","WR","RB","WR","TE","DST"),
                      Name=c(paste("Player",1:9,sep="")),
                      Salary = c(rnorm(9,5000,100)),
                      FPPG = c(rnorm(9,21,1)),
                      TeamSalary = rep(59600,9),
                      TotalPoints = rep(216.803,9),
                      Index = rep(2,9)))
data=rbind(data,data1)
data$Name = as.character(data$Name)

test2=NULL

ind = unique(data$Index)

for(j in 1:length(ind)){
  data1 = data[data$Index == ind[j],]
  points = 0
  salary = 0
  test1 = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 1,ncol=9))
  names(test1) = c("QB", "RB", "RB", "WR", "WR", "WR", "TE", "FLEX", "DST")
  for(i in 1:dim(test1)[2]){
    pos = names(test1)[i]
    if(pos == "FLEX"){
      player = data1[data1$Position %in% c("WR","TE","RB"),]
    } else {
      player = data1[data1$Position == pos,]
    }
    name = player$Name[which(player$FPPG == max(player$FPPG))]
    salary = salary + player$Salary[which(player$FPPG == max(player$FPPG))]
    points = points + player$FPPG[which(player$FPPG == max(player$FPPG))]
    data1 = data1[data1$Name != name,]
    test1[,i] = name
  }
  test1$TeamSalary = salary
  test1$TotalPoints = points
  test2 = rbind(test2,test1)
}
test2
```

Comment: Got some errors with this one.  I just reworked my questions.  Basically I have a dataframe of teams and just want to consolidate them down to 1 line with players, salary and points on that line.  Might be easier to do and will yeild a suitable result.  Let me know what you think.  Essentially I have a dataframe of thousand of teams and I want to collapse it down to one line per team, with names of players, total salary and total points on 1 line

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a team ID in your data frame though so how do you know which team the players are on?

Comment: They are listed in order so the first 9 are team 1, next 9 team 2 and so on.

Comment: used dplyr to create an index for teams, index <- group_indices(test1, TotalPoints, TeamSalary)  How can I use this to transpose the information I need?

Comment: you can probably loop by index now. if you extract the team info by the index, you should be able to use the loop from the response above by you can replace this 1:(nrow(data)/9) with something like this: 1:length(unique(index))

Comment: This is great, but I cant figure out how to swap in my larger dataset.  When I do it continues to print the same team over and over again.  What edit do I need to make to swap it in data frame with 10000 teams.

Comment: I think you probably just need to rename your dataset. If your dataset is currently called" test1" try and do this: data = test1. As long as your column names are the same as my examples above it should work. you can probably also comment out the last line - test2 and replace it with head(test2). That way it will only print out the first 6 rows

Comment: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "TeamSalary", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1
In addition: There were 27 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: can you post the first 6 rows of your data so I can see the column names of your dataset?

Comment: Just want to say thanks again. I appreciate you working with me today. It was a huge help

Comment: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = c("Jeremy Maclin", "Brandin Cooks" : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1  I am now getting this error when I run it on a much larger data set